# Categorizing a patient using FHIR?

Tags: hl7-fhir

We want to categorize patients in our system. For example, in organ transplant, we want to "tag" a Patient FHIR resource as a donor or recipient (ignoring the scenario where a living donor can later become a recipient) since these types of "patients" are stored separately in the back end system. So when someone does a PUT HTTP request with a patient resource, we need to know what kind of patient it is before we can do the update in the database.

It's hard to determine the best way to approach this.  Using the meta area seems promising, combined with the UsageContextType of "focus" perhaps, taking on values of "donor" or "recipient".

It's not clear though how to actually code something like this in a Patient resource (JSON for us).  Any guidance/examples would be very much appreciated.

Sadly, I think the FHIR folks are going down the same path they used with the V3 RIM....lots of impenetrable standard definitions, but very few practical examples of how to use some of these FHIR standards in the real world. But that is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand ignoring the scenario where someone can be both donor and recipient.   However, if you needed to, you could add an extension that differentiated.  You could also use Patient.meta.tag.

With the RIM there'd have been an esoteric modelling mechanism to define what you wanted, likely walking through 3-4 classes to get to one element (and a whole lot of fixed values along the way).  With FHIR, if you're doing something esoteric, you just define an extension.

If you see something in the core specification you find impenetrable, please submit a change request asking for the language to be improved.  (There's a "propose a change" link at the bottom of every page and registration is free.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to reply, Lloyd.  I'm only ignoring the both donor & recipient scenario to simplify the question.

Using the Patient.meta is something I thought looked promising.  But there are no examples of how to use that along with the UsageContextType (focus).  What I'm looking for is an actual example of what this would look like in a JSON Patient resource.

Almost all of the HL7 specifications that don't have concrete examples are "impenetrable".  Lack of such examples will hold back FHIR implementation by mere mortals. ;-)

Comment: There are examples of every FHIR resource - the FHIR publishing tools won't even function if there isn't at least one.  Obviously, we won't have examples that cover every possible edge case...

UsageContextType isn't available for Patient - it's intended for 'definitional' resources - e.g. profiles, value sets, protocols, questionnaires, etc.  It will let you find forms for humans vs. cows or infants vs. geriatrics.

Comment: Guess I'm stuck just using a custom extension for this. That works. Thanks